# Embed Payara in Java SE

Tags: java-ee-7, payara

Context: Existing JavaSE application written in Swing which fires up an embedded server (so far it was Jetty) but we need to switch to Java EE, so we thought about bringing in an enterprise container (candidates are: Payara, Tomee, Wildfly). 
The server should be able to run a web app based on dynamic input: web context, with its own web.xml, specific web resources which are not known at build time, so uber jar is not really an option for us. 
We have successfully started a web app on Payara using code like the following (this is not working code, but it shows the steps we took for using Payara)

```
GlassFish glassfish;
WebContainer container;
GlassFishRuntime glassfishRuntime =  = GlassFishRuntime.bootstrap();
glassfish = glassfishRuntime.newGlassFish();
glassfish.start();

// Access WebContainer
container = glassfish.getService(WebContainer.class);
WebContainerConfig config = new WebContainerConfig();
container.setConfiguration(config);

Context context = container.createContext(contextPathLocation);
m_webAppContexts.put(p_contextName, context);
WebListener listener = container.createWebListener("listener-1", HttpListener.class);
listener.setPort(myDynamicPortNumber);
container.addWebListener(listener);
container.addContext(context, myDynamicContextPath);
context.addServlet(myDynamicMapping, myServletName);
```

This is all working and a basic web application starts in Payara when invoked from our Java SE application.

We also have a fragment of web.xml declaring additional servlets that we want to bring in this dynamic deployment if given conditions are satisfied. 
What is the best way to override the existing web.xml with fragments from another web.xml? We need pointers to documentation, directions from more experienced Payara users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with Payara or Wildfly, as they work very differently from how Jetty works.
However, it is possible with Tomee.